# Specifier, adjunct, or complement? how to know? syntax

Tags: word-request, grammaticality, syntax, complements, adjuncts

How can I know if an embedded clause is a Specifier, an adjunct, or a complement?

For example, in a sentence like:

> One notion that nobody has mentioned yet was proposed during the conference.

Can you please explain to me the process of how to know if the embedded clause is a Specifier, an adjunct, or a complement?

I would really appreciate an explanation.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you know the terms and you know that they're different, what differences do **you** perceive between Specifier, Adjunct, and Complement?  For your information, the terms _specifier, adjunct,_ and _complement_ are frequently used with different senses in linguistics, so we need to know where **you're** coming from.

Comment: My understanding is, Specifiers are clausal subjects. Adjunct are relative clauses

Comment: You must have that backwards; not all adjuncts are relative clauses, but all relative clauses are adjuncts. And Specifiers are not always (or even ever?) clausal subjects. The problem with terminology is that there's so much of it, and it's all different.

Comment: Thank you! but what would be a possible explanation.

Comment: Relative clauses are neither adjuncts nor complements: they are generally modifiers, though the non-restrictive ones are supplements. In your example, "that nobody has mentioned yet" is a relative clause modifying the noun "notion". Adjuncts, on the other hand are modifiers in clause structure, where they modify verbs and verb phases. Complements are quite different and need more explanation. Specifier is not a function term like modifier and complement, so can mean virtually anything. Do you have a decent grammar book?

Comment: So, there is no complement phrase in such sentences. I thought the complement phrase would be "was raised" but it is away from the head.

Comment: See, the terms aren't being used in their proper distribution. @BillJ, who is an expert on this terminology, notes that _adjunct, complement, specifier,_ and _modifier_ are all part of this particular paradigm, and there are definitions and contrasts to learn before trying to identify specimens in the field.

Comment: @personallearner No, "was proposed" is not a complement. It's part of the verb phrase "was proposed during the conference", serving as the **predicate** of the sentence. Note that 'predicate' is a function term, just as 'modifier' and 'complement' are.

Comment: Thank you, BillJ!